# Normal implies self-ajoint

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $ V $ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $ \mathbb C $, and let $ T: V \rightarrow V $ be a linear operator.

(a) Show that $ T=0 \Leftrightarrow T^*=0 \Leftrightarrow TT^* \Leftrightarrow T^*T =0.  $

(b) Show that if $ T $ is self adjoint, and $ T^n=0 $ for some $ n $, then $ T=0 $.

(c) Show that if $ T $ is normal, and $ T^n=0 $ for some $ n $, then $ T=0 $. (Hint: Show that if $ T $ is normal then $ TT^* $ is self adjoint.)

(d) Give an example of $ V $ and $ T $ where $ T \neq 0 $ and $ T=0 $. Show directly that t is not normal.

My attempt:

(a) $ T=0 \Leftrightarrow Tv=0 \Leftrightarrow \lt Tv,Tv \gt = 0 \Leftrightarrow <T^*w,T^*w>=0 \Leftrightarrow <T^*w=0 \Leftrightarrow T^*=0 \Leftrightarrow TT^*=0 \Leftrightarrow T^*T=0 \Leftrightarrow TT^*=0. $

(b) Since T is self adjoint $ \ T=T^*$ So, $\ T^2 =T^*T=0 \Rightarrow \ T=0 $ and the base case holds. Suppose $ m $ is an integer for which the hypothesis holds. Then $\ T^m=0 \rightarrow \ T=0$

$ \ T^{m+1} = T^m . T^*=0\rightarrow T^*=T=0.$ by part (a). $(\ TT^*=0 \rightarrow \ T^*=0) $ Hence the results holds for all $\ n\in \mathbb N. $

(c) This is my first question. Since $ (ST)^* = T^*S^*$ we have $ (TT^*)^* = T^{**}T^* = TT^* $ which does not make sense. Where have I gone wrong?

(d) Let $ V= \mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} $ and suppose $ T $ is the linear transformation given by $ \begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 1  \\
    1       & 1   \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

How do I find the explicit linear transformation given by this matrix?

Are my solutions to part (a) and (b) correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quick correction to (a): you should emphasize that $T = 0 \iff Tv = 0$ **for all $v \in V$**.  For all steps with $v,w$, it should be clear that the equality is meant to hold for all such vectors (or at least over a basis).

For (b), your proof by induction is faulty.  In particular, it's not clear how you deduce
$$
T^mT^* = 0 \implies T^* = T = 0
$$
this is not a clear application of part (a).  Instead, I would note that if $k<m \leq 2k$, then
$$
T^m = 0 \implies T^{2k} = 0 \implies (T^k)(T^k)^* = 0 \implies T^k = 0
$$
which allows us to set up a proof by strong induction.  (If it helps, take $k = \lceil m/2 \rceil$).

For (c), you have not gone wrong at all: $TT^*$ is necessarily self-adjoint, regardless of whether $T$ is normal.  The trick is to note that
$$
T^m = 0 \iff (T^m)(T^m)^* = 0 \iff (TT^*)^m = 0 \iff TT^* = 0 \iff T = 0
$$

For (d), remember that $V$ should be an inner product space. Consider instead
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
The linear transformation given by $A$ is $T(v) = Av$.